# Error - Cannot resolve identifier when trying to use executionListener- Activiti

Tags: activiti

I am trying to invoke a method from activiti sequence flow but I am getting the below error, can someone please help me fix this issue?

```
<sequenceFlow id="finalTask" name="finalTask" sourceRef="chargeAccount" targetRef="theEnd">
            <extensionElements>
                <activiti:executionListener
                    expression="${EscalationListener.escalate(execution, 'kermit')}"
                    event="end" />
            </extensionElements>
        </sequenceFlow>
```

**Error:**

Caused by: org.activiti.engine.impl.javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier 'EscalationListener'
            at org.activiti.engine.impl.juel.AstIdentifier.eval(AstIdentifier.java:8

**Java code:**

```
import org.activiti.engine.HistoryService;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;

public class EscalationListener {
    HistoryService historyService;

    public void escalate(DelegateExecution execution, String otherTaskId)
            throws Exception {

        historyService.createHistoricTaskInstanceQuery().taskOwner(otherTaskId)
                .finished();
        //System.out.println("called history service" + otherTaskId);

        // do some stuff with the task
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `EscalationListener` as a process variable :

```
runtimeService.setVariable(yourExecutionId, "escalationListener" , new EscalationListener());
```

You can also add process variable before starting the process:

```
runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("someKey", processVariables);
```

processVariables is a `Map<String, Object>` where you put `EscalationListener` object

or declare it as Spring bean to access it in process definition:

```
<bean id="EscalationListener" class="com.test.activiti.listener.EscalationListener" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<activiti:executionListener
                expression="${EscalationListener.escalate(execution, 'kermit')}"
                event="end" />
```

try to change `EscalationListener` per `escalationListener` here. I had problems sometimes because of this sometimes.

Sadly this `PropertyNotFoundException: Cannot resolve identifier` happens quite a lot when you have errors. And at least for me, it's not helping you...